# Multiplying Arrays Where Condition - Rails Associations

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have Leadactions that belong to Actions that belong to Companies that Belong to Agencies.

What I'm trying to do is at the Agency level get a sum of the values(defined in a column in Leadactions table) for all actions of the companies that belong to the agency.

I have the two arrays needed but I don't know how to properly sum it up.

Models
    class Leadaction < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :action
    end

```
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_one :leadaction
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :agency
    has_many :actions
    belongs_to :agency
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :companies
    has_many :actions, through: :companies
    has_many :leadactions, through: :actions
end
```

Controllers

```
class AgenciesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = current_user
        @agency = @user.agency
        @companies = @agency.companies.all
        @leads = @agency.actions.where.not(leadaction_id: '').map(&:leadaction_id.to_proc)
        @leadvalues = Leadaction.all.map { |v| v.value }
    end
```

@leads is giving me an array that looks like this: [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2] which is the leadaction_id column for the association.

@leadvalues is giving me: [[1, 300], [2, 6000], [3, 300]] which is the Leadaction.id and Leadaction.value

I don't know how to get it so everywhere there's a 1 in that first array it'll show a 300, everywhere there is a 2 it'll show 6000, everywhere there is a 3 it'll show 300. So I'd end up with an array that looks like:
[300, 6000, 300, 300, 300, 6000, 6000, 6000, 300, 300, 300, 6000, 6000, 300, 6000, 6000]

is there a way I can do this? Please help my mind is mush from working on this 1 problem for at least 12 hours straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it for now...although I'm sure this is not the most efficient way.

Agency Controller:

```
class AgenciesController < ApplicationController

def show
#market value of leads all time
    @leadvalues = @agencyleads.map { |l| Leadaction.find(l.leadaction_id) }
    @leadvalueat = @leadvalues.map { |l| l.value }
end
```

View:

```
<%= @leadvalueat.empty? ? '$0' : number_to_currency(@leadvalueat.sum, precision: 0) %>
```